# Speech to text in Word 2007

Tags: microsoft-word, vba, speech-to-text

How to enable Speech to Text in Microsoft Word 2007 ? I have found guides for text to speech but I am rather interested into speech to text.

Comment: which version of windows?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like speech recognition was removed from Office 2007.

> Speech recognition features are not available in the 2007 Microsoft Office system programs.
>
> To use speech recognition features, run Windows Speech Recognition in Windows Vista.
>
> If your operating system is Microsoft Windows XP, you must run a previous version of a Microsoft Office system program to use speech recognition features.

[Source](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/publisher-help/what-happened-to-speech-recognition-HA010224356.aspx?CTT=1)

Answer (score 1):

Speech To Test is a whole new ballgame, and is as not easy to handle as Text To Speech.

You will probably need a third party software, like "[Dragon NaturallySpeaking](http://www.nuance.com/naturallyspeaking/)", which can only handle Dutch, English, French, German, Italian, and Spanish.

There are also other (some free) software which claims to do the job (only English, though), but I was not able to find a an alternative to "Dragon" that really worked.

And if you want to convert speech which is in another language than those above, you are (like me!) basicly out of luck...

Answer (score 0):

Windows Vista and Windows 7 have built-in speech recognition technology, that can be used to input text into documents...

The Microsoft Speech Recognition page (for Vista, but applies to Windows 7 also): http://www.microsoft.com/enable/products/windowsvista/speech.aspx

To start the program; just type "Windows Speech Recognition" into your search box on the Start menu, and hit 'Enter'.  Have fun! :)